# withSpinner() Not working while waiting for multiple infoBoxOutputs to display

Tags: r, shiny

Currently the application won't run with the error "type %in% 0:8 are not all TRUE". Is it possible to use withSpinner() or should I look at alternatives?

```
fluidRow(
  column(12
      box(title = "Test", width = NULL, status = "primary",
          withSpinner(
          div(infoBoxOutput("test")),
          div(infoBoxOutput("test1")),
         )
       )
     ),
```

Comment: First of all, you need to share a minimal reproducible example of your problem that others can run. That means code and any dataset. Secondly, you might be encountering this error because you are passing to values to the withSpinner( ) function when it expects one value at a time. Also, you need to specify the type of spinner in the function withSpinner(infoBoxOutput("test"), type = 1). But ideally, share your code so that others can reproduce the problem and be able to properly troubleshoot and not just guess.